# Mariadb with more than one node each node will have recent 1 year data

Tags: mariadb, time-series-database

I am creating a saas which will then have time based data every seconds for example.
I want horizontal scalling when data reach its limit of 1 year.
after 1 year old data should be shift to another server so only 1 year data is available on 1st node
2nd will have 1 year old data and 3rd will have 2 years old data so on.

let me know which db tool I should use to achieve this and how?
or
let me know better solution if any

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [MariaDB Spider storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-storage-engine-core-concepts/) which is a sharding engine that allows you to partition the data e.g. by range so that data in a certain range will be stored on a certain backend server.

Let's say you have a table with `year` column. You can then say that values in a particular year should go to a particular backend server. See some [example use cases here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-use-cases/).

This will give you node 1 for the first year, node 2 for the second year and so on, and no shifting of data, but that is probably better anyway. You can always rename the servers, if that helps.

If you're storing a new row every second, that means 31,536,000 rows per year, which is probably absolutely fine, though it's always a good idea to make sure the table(s) are optimally designed especially when you're storing a lot of data like this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel obligated to warn you that the result will not live up to expectations.  Does your application look at the data older than a few months?  I suspect not.  That means that one server will be heavily used and the others will be collecting 
dust.

Or maybe you have big queries that reach back in time and build reports of the data over time?  In that case, a much better solution is to build and maintain "summary tables" for your "time-series-database".  The reports will run 10 times as fast, and the summary table(s) will be one-tenth the size of the "Fact" table.  At which point, you may be willing to toss the old data (using `PARTITIONing` to make that efficient) or simply get a bigger disk.

More on summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
Partitioning for purging old time-series data:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint